# Count By and Find By in same Query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to build a single query using a JPA method name that finds all of the results based on a parameter, then counts based on a second parameter.

Say I have data that looks like this:

- ID | Word  | Who said it
- 1  | Apple | Person1
- 2  | Banana| Person1
- 3  | Apple | Person1
- 4  | Apple | Person2

I want to pass in a "Who said it" String and receive a histogram of unique words and how many times they said it. So, if I pass in "Person1", I want to receive:

- Apple: 2
- Banana: 1

How would I combine both the `findByWhoSaidIt(String whoSaidIt)` with a `countByWord`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `@Query` annotation with a native SQL query:

```
@Query(value = "select word, count(*) where who_said_it = :person group by word",
        nativeQuery=true)
Object[] whatWasSaidBy(String person)
```

Comment: Is writing out a query by hand the preferred method in this case? Is that because the query is too complicated for a JPA method name? I'd prefer to do it without writing the SQL by hand, but if this is the only way, I'll do it

Comment: Yes! Derived queries (from method names) work only for simple queries and are only intended for that. A good rule of thumb is: If you have to think hard how you have to name a query method it's not a good fit for derived queries. 

In this case it is even impossible to use a derived query.

Comment: Interesting, I was really hoping I could combine two derived queries to make JPA do all the work for me, but oh well.

I've accepted your answer, thank you! But if you wouldn't mind - I'm getting an error in my code (which is more complex than the example I've written up here), saying effectively "column 'word' not found". Is there a way to have Java/JPA list all available columns that I could use in my handwritten query?

Comment: > Is there a way to have Java/JPA list all available columns that I could use in my handwritten query? 
I don't think so. If you are using JPQL the "columns" are the property names. If you are using SQL (`nativeQuery=true`) they are the actual table columns. 
If you don't find it, post a new question with the entity, the query and the complete stack trace. I'm confident that we figure that one out fast.